# Logging outgoing request with GeoServer & MapFish

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish, log

I use GeoServer printing module (based on MapFish) to print my preview map in my application (uses Mapstore app).

My problem is that my WMS service is not in my PDF.

What I want, is to log outgoing request to know what MapFish doing with my service and layers.

For example, this is my JSON request var send to printing

```
{
    "units": "m",
    "srs": "EPSG:4326",
    "layout": "A4_no_legend",
    "dpi": 300,
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "outputFilename": "snapshot-map",
    "geodetic": true,
    "mapTitle": "",
    "comment": "",
    "layers": [
        {
            "baseURL": "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/",
            "opacity": 1,
            "singleTile": false,
            "type": "XYZ",
            "maxExtent": [
                -20037508.3392,
                -20037508.3392,
                20037508.3392,
                20037508.3392
            ],
            "tileSize": [
                256,
                256
            ],
            "extension": "png",
            "resolutions": [
                156543.03390625,
                78271.516953125,
                39135.7584765625,
                19567.87923828125,
                9783.939619140625,
                4891.9698095703125,
                2445.9849047851562,
                1222.9924523925781,
                611.4962261962891,
                305.74811309814453,
                152.87405654907226,
                76.43702827453613,
                38.218514137268066,
                19.109257068634033,
                9.554628534317017,
                4.777314267158508,
                2.388657133579254,
                1.194328566789627,
                0.5971642833948135
            ],
            "path_format": "/${z}/${y}/${x}"
        },
        {
            "baseURL": "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Boundaries_and_Places/MapServer/tile/",
            "opacity": 1,
            "singleTile": false,
            "type": "XYZ",
            "maxExtent": [
                -20037508.3392,
                -20037508.3392,
                20037508.3392,
                20037508.3392
            ],
            "tileSize": [
                256,
                256
            ],
            "extension": "png",
            "resolutions": [
                156543.03390625,
                78271.516953125,
                39135.7584765625,
                19567.87923828125,
                9783.939619140625,
                4891.9698095703125,
                2445.9849047851562,
                1222.9924523925781,
                611.4962261962891,
                305.74811309814453,
                152.87405654907226,
                76.43702827453613,
                38.218514137268066,
                19.109257068634033,
                9.554628534317017,
                4.777314267158508,
                2.388657133579254,
                1.194328566789627,
                0.5971642833948135
            ],
            "path_format": "/${z}/${y}/${x}"
        },
        {
            "baseURL": "MY_DOMAIN/geoserver/wms?",
            "version": "1.3.0",
            "opacity": 1,
            "singleTile": true,
            "type": "WMS",
            "layers": [
                "LAYER_NAME"
            ],
            "format": "image/png",
            "styles": [
                ""
            ],
            "customParams": {
                "bbox": "-10,10,35,50",
                "TRANSPARENT": true,
                "TILED": true,
                "EXCEPTIONS": "application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage",
                "scaleMethod": "accurate",
                "CRS": "EPSG:4326",
                "SRS": "EPSG:4326"
            }
        }
    ],
    "pages": [
        {
            "center": [
                30.108827,
                60.205444
            ],
            "scale": 3000,
            "rotation": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And I don't how MapFish uses it.

I think it create request like this:
`https://MY_DOMAIN/geoserver/wms?BBOX=XXX&WIDTH=3250&HEIGHT=871&format_options=dpi%3A300&map_resolution=300&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&bbox=XXXX&STYLES=&LAYERS=XXX&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&TILED=true&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&scaleMethod=accurate&DPI=300&TRANSPARENT=true` but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

If you turn GeoServer logging upto GeoServer Developer (under the `global settings` page) you will see the parameters and any errors in the log file (usually in `$DATA_DIR/logs/geoserver.log`).